# Downgrade Python 3.7 to 3.5 on Raspbian Buster

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, debian-buster

So it seems like Buster comes default with 2.7 on load and an alternate 3.7 version of Python. However, I am using this Raspberry Pi 3 B+ just for an application that is only compatible with Python 3.5. How do run Python 3.5 as default version or remove 3.7 entirely from Buster?

Answer (score 1):

I truly believe that you can just install python3.5 from the source repos.

If you want to install python 3.5.4 :

`sudo apt-get install python3.5`

If you want to install python 3.5.3 (Debian Stretch) :

Edit as root `/etc/apt/source.list` and add the following repos,

`deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free`

`rpi firmware deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui`

Then install the specific package version from the target repo using the following command :

`sudo apt-get install python3.5 -t stretch`

If want to install pip3.5 (which i guess you would need) :

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

`python3.5 ./get-pip.py`

Answer (score 0):

just need to follow 1 step

do not remove python3.7 directly it will cause problems

install 3.5 and directly start using it.
after 3.5 install you can remove python 3.7

keep it simple. :)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to remove package any package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge package_name
```

So in your case:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.7
```

After if you want specific version download in manually and install. For example 3.5.2

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/Python-3.5.2.tar.xz
tar -xvf Python-3.5.2.tar.xz
cd Python-3.5.2
./configure
make -j4
make install
```

Comment: uninstalling the Python 3.7 from the Raspberry Pi caused a lot of instabilities and also it is unable to reboot back into the OS.

Comment: do not know about it. In this case one could just install python 3.5.2 and run it

Comment: I had similar woes trying to revert from 3.7 to 3.5 via above method. Eventually had to scrap everything and start over. There has to be a way to make this happen...

Comment: Removing the system python is a bad idea. @Stigma does not need to remove python 3.7 to use python 3.5 for their project.